# CSS3 3D Transformations not working in Chrome (Linux)

Tags: linux, html, css

You will need Linux Chrome to see this. On my dev site [spoilmebox.com](http://www.spoilmebox.com) (see three boxes on bottom), my backface is showing through. How do I fix this?

CSS...

```
.Qcontainer {
position: relative;
-webkit-perspective: 800;
-moz-perspective: 800;
perspective: 800;
background: none;
}
.pumpkinhead {
width:100%;
height:15em;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transition: 1s;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transition: 1s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transition: 1s;
}
.Qcontainer:hover .pumpkinhead {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.face {
position: absolute;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
z-index: 5;
}
.back {
width: 66%;
height:127%;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
background: #000000;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,
rgba(0,0,0,0.65)0%,
rgba(0,0,0,0)100%);
z-index: 4;
padding: 15%;
}
```

html...

```
<div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4 Qcontainer">
                <div class="pumpkinhead">
                    <div class="face front">
                        <h2 class="g2-unit-header">...</h2>
                        <p style="min-height: 240px;">...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">...</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="face back">
                        <p>this is my back fool!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Notice I am using bootstrap (span4) but I don't believe this is messing up because it is working in Chrome (Windows) and Firefox.

The source for this code was ***Responsive Web Design with HTML5 and CSS3 by Ben Frain***

I am already using jQuery and JavaScript on this site, so not looking for an alternative. I want to support this new CSS3 technology if I can get it to play with most of the browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, from what I can tell, a bug in a recent build of Chrome on Linux (I haven't tested on other platforms yet); you will notice that every other site utilising the same CSS transformations now has a problem with the backface showing through. I've also noticed on my own site that perspective is no longer being rendered.

Whilst annoying, we must remember that prefixed CSS features are still experimental ones, and we shouldn't be relying on them to remain stable or even to remain present.

Comment: I just hope, as they come out with experimental projects like so, they are not judging the popularity by uses. It would be easy to adopt such a feature, but if you know it could go away, make it difficult to show any interest.