# -webkit-transform: rotateY fails on Mac OS

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, webkit, transform

The cards are supposed to flip to reveal text on the back side. This works perfectly fine on my windows laptop and also on phones but seems to not work on Mac. Why is that?

I found a similar question asked on 2013 [-webkit-transform: rotateY fails on Mac OS (in Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365899/webkit-transform-rotatey-fails-on-mac-os-in-chrome?noredirect=1#comment100921420_16365899)
I hope it's either been fixed or there's a workaround for this by now.

Please help. Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/adititipnis/pen/mNrBGj)

Code:
HTML:

```
<div id="services" class="servicesSection">
        <div id="production" class="serviceCard service music">
            <h4 class="card__face card__face--front">PRODUCTION</h4>
            <p class="card__face card__face--back">This includes the creation of the complete backing track with
                state of the art sound design and FX.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="songwriting" class="serviceCard service video">
            <h4 class="card__face card__face--front">SONGWRTING / COMPOSITION</h4>
            <p class="card__face card__face--back">We create a melody from scratch based on the concept of your song
                and write lyrics as well.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="vocal" class="serviceCard service event">
            <h4 class="card__face card__face--front">VOCAL PRODUCTION</h4>
            <p class="card__face card__face--back">We polish and tune your vocals. This includes all the vocal FX &
                stacking to make it sound well-rounded and professional. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="mixing" class="serviceCard service tech">
            <h4 class="card__face card__face--front">MIXING/MASTERING</h4>
            <p class="card__face card__face--back">Audio post-production to give you a release ready track which
                will be of top-notch quality and match industry standards.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sound" class="serviceCard service music">
            <h4 class="card__face card__face--front">SOUND SUITES</h4>
            <p class="card__face card__face--back">We tailor-make sound packages for your brand. We will create
                music to emulate your brand's message. This will be completely unique to your brand to give it the
                recall value it deserves.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.servicesSection {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        /* height: 100vh; */
        /* scroll-snap-align: center; */
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    .service {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 1;
        width: 25vw;
        height: 25vw;
    }

.musicService .serviceCard h4 {
    margin: auto
}

.service a {
    object-fit: contain;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.service img {
    object-fit: contain;
    margin-top: auto
}

.service h4 {
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 20px
}

.homeService, .service {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: #fff 1px solid;
}

.video {
        /* background-color: #3b5998; */
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #8E0E00, #1F1C18)
    }
    .music {
        /* background-color: #d61b1e */
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1F1C18, #8E0E00)
    }
    .event {
        /* background-color: #FF7514; */
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1F1C18, #203A43, #2C5364)
    }
    .tech {
        /* background-color: #38908f; */
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2C5364, #1F1C18)
    }

.serviceCard {
  height: 25vw !important;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: transform 500ms;
    /* transition-delay: 0.500ms; */
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateX(0%) rotateY(0deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: 500ms;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 500ms;
    -moz-transition: 500ms;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 500ms;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* .serviceCard * {
    pointer-events: none;
} */

.serviceCard.is-flipped {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    backface-visibility: visible;
}

.card__face .card__face--back {
    /* -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden; */
    -webkit-transition: 100ms;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transition: 100ms;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transition: 100ms;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transition: 100ms;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transition: 100ms;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.card__face {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.card__face--back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    font-weight: 900;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.serviceCard h4, .serviceCard p').on('mouseover', function () {
        event.target
        $(this).parent().addClass('is-flipped');
        var parent = event.target.parentElement.id
        bindMouseLeave(parent)
    });

    function bindMouseLeave(parent) {
        $(this).on('mouseleave', function () {
            // setTimeout(() => {
            if (!event.target.parentElement.id || event.target.parentElement.id != parent)
                $('#' + parent).removeClass('is-flipped');
            // }, 1500);
        });
    }

  })
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `transform: rotateY;` as well as `-webkit-transform: rotateY;`?

Comment: yes. I've tried every vendor prefix possible.

Comment: Try adding `display: block;` to the `.serviceCard` class.   See same issue [here](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/solved-webkit-transform-not-working/) on CSS-Tricks